# Can I take bear spray across land borders in the Balkans and Caucasus?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, borders, regulations, balkans, caucasus

I am walking to the Caucasus and bought some bear spray for self-defence against bears in Slovenia. If I disclose that I have bear spray in my tent bag to the border guards along the way, are they likely to tolerate me taking it across the following borders: Croatia-Bosnia-Montenegro-Albania-Greece-Turkey-Georgia-Azerbaijan?

Comment: Unless you're travelling by plane, I see no reason why it would cause problems. IMO, no need to mention it upfront.

Comment: Several sources claim that pepper spray is illegal in Greece, e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pepper_spray#cite_ref-54) citing the US State Department.  I haven't found a reference for the actual Greek law, though.

Comment: @Johnnyjanko surely the border guards are likely to ask whether I have any any of a long list of items in my rucksack, and one word in that list is likely to be "weapons"?

Comment: They can tolerate it for a price $$$. I am also certain it will be used against you in exchange for bribes. Also, why do you need bear mace from Slovenia in Georgia? That's a long walk with bear mace. Have you considered leaving that in Slovenia?

Comment: @novice They might ask, but in most of the countries you mentioned it's nowhere near likely. They'll just check your documents and maybe check your luggage for drugs. But since you'll be travelling opposite the usual flow of drugs and migrants, they'll likely not care too much. Maybe in Turkey they will, but not in the Balkans.